# How to link tables sharing the same data on Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I would like two tables or more in Excel to share the same data so they can be filtered separately to show different chunks of data. Sharing the same data means I want modifications in table A to affect data in table B **and vice-versa**.

So far I've been able to import data from A to B and any changes in A will affect B, however I'm not able to have changes in B affect data in A.

Is it at all possible and what feature should I use?

Comment: I don't know if I'm wording this right. Please let me know if I'm not clear.

Comment: [This might help](http://superuser.com/questions/864613/how-to-mirror-cells-in-excel-2013/864659#864659)!

Comment: That's pretty close, although it matches cells with one another by cell reference, so whenever I filter one table it will also filter the other table, which is not the desired behavior. I want filtering from one table not to affect filtering on the other table.

Comment: You can edit my answer to help you... But I don't fully understand your question because I don't know how your tables look like precisely...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a third table C to hold the data, and which will take any modifications to the data that you need to make, and tables A and B become reports on the single source of data.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but it won't fit my purpose from a working strategy point of view, where I need several people to edit the data simultaneously on separately filtered data tables showing only the chunk of data that is relevant to each person.